# See manifest.xml in developer console

Tags: android, android-manifest

I used a 3rd party companies software to make my app and they added it to the Android market for me.  I'm trying to find the manifest file but I don't even know what it looks like.  Can someone please guide me where to find it in my developers console and tell me what to look for please?

Comment: Can you specify if you are using en environment different than eclipse? And , have you built the output files yourself?
It will also help if you make sure you already looked for "AndroidManifest.xml" using your pc's search file tool :) , basic but first thing to do

Answer (score 1):

First, "at this time" it is not possible to retrieve your application from the developers console.

Assuming a 3rd party companies software builded and released your app called "application.apk" and you don't have access to the source (and AndroidManifest.xml), you should be able to download the application from google play.

An .apk is similar to a zip compressed file, consequently you can unzip it.
The AndroidManifest.xml file is simply at the root of the uncompressed archive. In order to be able to read its content, you might need tools like http://code.google.com/p/android-apktool/ or other ones.